# dynamically changing div width - weird problem

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a div tag and I dynamically set the width of the div... to start with it the width will be 10% and then it will increase based on the value the user enters. This is how I am setting the value dynamically from the javascript. It works fine in FF and Chrome. It works in a weird way in IE... if I put an alert box after setting the width in the JS it works but if I remove the alert box the div width doesn't change and it stays at the old value.

Can somebody give me some insight on this?

This is the sample code and newval can be anything between range 0 to 100

```
document.getElementById('test'+id).style.width = newval + '%'
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please post code reproducing the problem or a link to an example.

Comment: We need an example of the actual HTML, JS and CSS.  Percent width can be tricky.

Comment: document.getElementById('test'+id).style.width = newval + '%';

Comment: Try setting zoom: 1 in the CSS for the div. This tells IE that the div itself is responsible for rendering itself, not the document's body :)

Comment: setting zoom doesnt work Darhazer

Comment: I think we need more code to see how you are calling it (onload, oready, onclick, etc.). I set up a simple test here, and it worked fine in IE and IE compatibility mode: http://jsfiddle.net/GQnCy/5/

Comment: am calling the js function on click of the image. The argument is the value between 0 to 100. It works fine in other browsers. It also updates the width if i put a alert statement to block the execution. Wondering why it wont work if the alert statement is removed

Comment: Did you check the sample of @Aaron Ray?

Answer (score 1):

Try add the `;` symbol at the end of expression, and concat the result value with "":

```
document.getElementById('test' + id).style.width = "" + newval + '%';
```

Comment: i did try to append an empty string in front and it doesnt help. Regarding the semicolon i forgot to put it in the post and also since everything is on a new line semicolon should be a problem

Comment: @htmllearner Then you should add more code - we can not help you with this amount of code.